# Comprobar si existe el archivo en una carpeta

Tags: python

Quiero comprobar si en la ruta **file** existe algun archivo que contenga la string **roll**, independientemente de su extensión. Igualmente, si el archivo se llama roller, me lo de por bueno. Aquí mi intento:

```
import os
file = os.listdir('C:/Mi/Ruta')

if file.__contains__("roll"):
    print ("ok")
```

Comment: ¿Que contenga la cadena "roll" en el nombre o como contenido del fichero?

Comment: en el nombre, ya sea una carpeta llamada roller o un png con el nombre troll, por ejemplo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Casi lo tienes. `os.listdir()` te devuelve una lista, por tanto la comprobación `file.__contains__()` busca en esa lista. Ya que lo que buscas es la cadena "roll", sólo te dará `True` si en la lista hay un elemento que sea esa cadena `"roll"`, y no si ese elemento contiene la subcadena "roll", que es lo que necesitas.

La solución es iterar por la lista `file` (que por cierto, mejor llamaríamos `files` pues contiene en general varios elementos), y mirar si cada uno de los elementos (que será una cadena), contiene la subcadena `"roll"`.

Por cierto que el uso de `__contains__()` es muy inusual, y lo normal es mirar si `subcadena in cadena` (internamente el operador `in` causa que se invoque `.__contains__()` pero es raro invocarlo explícitamente).

Por tanto la solución que buscas sería:

```
import os
files = os.listdir('C:/Mi/Ruta')

for file in files:
  if "roll" in file:
     print("ok")
     break
else:
  print("No encontrado")
```

Observa que el `else` pertenece al `for` y no al `if`. Es una característica propia de python que no existe en otros lenguajes. El `else` de un bucle se ejecutará sólo si el bucle se agota (y no se ejecutará si se sale de él con `break`)

También puedes evitar el uso del bucle explícito haciendo uso de la función `any()` que itera por una serie de booleanos y retorna `True` tan pronto como encuentre que uno de ellos es `True`. Juntando esto con una expresión generadora el código puede quedar más limpio (ya que evitas la extraña estructura `for...else` y el uso del `break`):

```
import os
files = os.listdir('C:/Mi/Ruta')

if any("roll" in file for file in files):
  print("Ok")
else:
  print("No se encuentra")
```

### Actualización

Si la búsqueda de "roll" debe ser insensible a mayúsculas/minúsculas (es decir, debe aceptar tanto "roll" como "ROLL" pero también casos intermedios como "Roll", "roLL", etc. puede hacerse de forma sencilla pasando a minúsculas el nombre del fichero a la hora de compararlo. Es decir, la comparación sería `"roll" in file.lower()`.

Esto puede hacerse con cualquiera de los dos enfoques antes vistos. Por ejemplo, con el último:

```
import os
files = os.listdir('C:/Mi/Ruta')

if any("roll" in file.lower() for file in files):
  print("Ok")
else:
  print("No se encuentra")
```

Comment: Gracias por la elaborada respuesta, pero no me ha funcionado, ya que el nombre del archivo no es exactamente 'roll'

Comment: ¡Y aún así debería funcionar! El código no está buscando que el nombre sea exactamente "roll", sino que _contanga_ la sub-cadena "roll". ¿Por qué dices que no te ha funcionado? ¿Podrías mostrar un ejemplo de los nombres de fichero que contiene tu carpeta? ¿Podría tratarse tal vez de un problema de mayúsculas/minúsculas?

Comment: Exactamente, se trata de un problema de mayúsculas, ya que el archivo que contiene la carpeta tiene la ''r'' mayúscula. ¿Este problema no puede solucionarse?

Comment: @andyio Sí, no es muy complicado. He añadido una ampliación a la respuesta